# Open jupyter notebook with app-specific conda environment with click on icon for Windows?

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook

I would like to make some tools available for my lab-workers. Usually, I develop and use my tools in jupyter notebooks. Though, big parts of my workgroup run Windows and require easy to use tools. There is a really nice tool called `appmode` for jupyter notebooks that hides all code and only shows app controls and output. Now, I could reimplement everything and setup a flask app, but essentially the notebook provides already everything needed. Though, it still requires users to start the notebook server etc. I wonder how I can deliver a jupyter notebook so that the user can basically click on an icon.

Then the a jupyter notebook using an app-specific conda environment should be started.

I am way more familiar with programming in Linux environments. So, this kind of tasks give me headaches.